# Rename columns that contain string match in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with >1000 columns that are named like this

```
df <- data.frame(ABC.efg.Basketball_seasonxx = c(0, 3), 
HIJK.LM.Baseball_season33 = c(5, 9))

  ABC.efg.Basketball_seasonxx HIJK.LM.Baseball_season33
1                           0                         5
2                           3                         9
```

wished output:

```
  Basketball Baseball
1          0        5
2          3        9
```

Using `dplyr`, I want to change the name of all columns to "Basketball" or "Baseball" whenever they contain the string "Basketball" or "Baseball", regardless of what other strings or symbols are in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `sub` to capture the word (`\\w+`) between the `.` and the `_` and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured word

```
 sub(".*\\.(\\w+)_.*", "\\1", names(df))
[1] "Basketball" "Baseball"
```

---

Or with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(names(df), "\\.(\\w+)_", group = 1)
[1] "Basketball" "Baseball"
```

Or if it is specific word, use

```
names(df) <- str_extract(names(df), "Bask?et?ball")
df
  Basketball Baseball
1          0        5
2          3        9
```

---

Or if it is only to rename columns having 'Basketball' or Baseball in the column names

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   rename_with(~ str_extract(.x, "Basketball|Baseball") , 
       matches("Basketball|Baseball"))
```

-output

```
   Basketball Baseball
1          0        5
2          3        9
```